# Show terminal and database sections on IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm trying to show terminal and database sections on IntelliJ IDEA 17.1.3 but I'm not winning. Am I not doing it right by hovering on the bottom left corner or by going to View and Tools Windows? Any idea on how to go about this?

Comment: `Alt+F12` brings up the terminal. You can show the database view with `Ctrl+Shift+A` and `Database`.

Comment: @C-Otto I tried that but no luck, as for the database one it pops up a search box saying Enter action or Option name.

Comment: You have to type "Database" in the search box to get the database view.

Comment: @eldix_ type in "database" and click it then click the + button in the top left of that window, you can then begin a connection to your database

Comment: Please make sure the Terminal plugin is enabled (go to Plugins in Settings).

Comment: I think there's some voodoo going on in my machine, I still can't get those views. I'm gonna download the latest version which is something I'm avoiding and see if it comes with all that set up.